# Automate string "subsetting"

Tags: r, string

If I have something like this:

```
paste0(1:3,sep=",")[3]
```

I thought of something like this:

```
paste0(1:3,sep=",")[length(.)]
```

which obviously won't work but the idea is to automatically capture the result without saving it.

**Question**
How can I automate selection corresponding to the length? I've narrowed down to this as the problem I want to solve(remove the last comma introduced by `paste0`) might be better solved with a `gsub` like solution.

**Expected Output**

```
"3,"
```

Or better, simply:

```
"1,","2,","3"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to use `%>%`

```
library(magrittr)
paste0(1:3,sep=",") %>%
        last
#[1] "3,"
```

Or for any index

```
paste0(1:3, sep=",") %>%
          magrittr::extract(., length(.))
#[1] "3,"
```

Also, to get the last output

```
paste0(1:3,sep=",") %>% 
  replace(., length(.), substring(.[length(.)], 1, nchar(.[length(.)]) -1))
#[1] "1," "2," "3"
```